# Contact Form 7 placeholder text traslate using wpml plugin

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am currently using Contact Form 7.I have created a contact form as follows:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-10 contact-form box-bg-style">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 input-type">[text* name id:name class:input-round  placeholder "Name*"]</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 input-type">[text subject id:subject class:input-round placeholder "Betreff"]</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 input-type">[email* email id:email class:input-round placeholder "E-Mail-Adresse*"]</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 input-type">[tel tel-632 id:phone class:input-round placeholder "Telefon"]</div>
<div class="col-12 input-type">[text adress id:adress class:input-round placeholder "Adresse"]</div>
<div class="col-12 input-type">[textarea message 40x4 id:message class:input-round placeholder "Nachricht"]</div>
<div class="col-12 input-type">[submit class:submit-button class:button class:align-text-center "SENDEN"]<span class="contact-text">Die eingegebene E-Mail-Adresse wird nur zum Zweck der Übertragung verwendet.</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It's in Germain Language....
But I want to separate the text for that French

Now I use the WPML plugin for text translation.

But I could not make my text and change. as per the i read wpml documentation, but it did not work.

Any idea for placeholder text traslate using wpml plugin.

Contact Form 7 placeholder text traslate using wpml plugin

Comment: as I know there is no way to translate shortcode parameters. as a solution you can duplicate your form then translate and use it.

Comment: Check this tutorial https://wpml.org/compatibility/2019/02/announcing-contact-form-7-ml/

Comment: Sorry i have read this documentaion but it's not helpfull. So please another idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solve this solution.

This plugin provided by WPML:
**WPML’s Classic or Advanced Translation Editor**

No need for that one.

So you can create 2 contact forms and separate the two short-code and manage.

Please see attached image. ( contact.png )

[image]